# 'That' Apposition Clause and Commas

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

1. The expectation, that ...., is far from reality.
2. The expectation that .... is far from reality.

Question: Is it necessary to have commas around the apposition clause starting with "that" in the examples above, or is it optional? I seem to have never been corrected by not putting commas around the apposition clause back in school, but I might be misremembering.

Note: The question's been already answered in the comment section. No more answers needed.

Comment: It depends on whether the content clause is intended to be a supplement, (non-defining), or integrated (defining). We can't tell without knowing what the full sentence is, or what the writer intended.

Comment: Please read about [restrictive clauses](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_clause.htm) and [non-restrictive clauses](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm). If you are still confused after reading this material, edit your question to explain exactly why you are confused.

Comment: Incidentally, modern grammar doesn't admit content clauses as appositives. To be on the safe side, I would label them simply as either complements (without punctuation) or supplements (with punctuation).

Comment: I see. First, a big thank you to both your responses.

Comment: @BillJ The clause I had in mind more closely aligned itself with being restrictive, as I wanted the sentence to be sound on its own. To put in another way, the content/appositive clause above in non-restrictive/supplementary form will be harder to stand on its own. This also nicely aligns with the corrections that I’ve received back in school, which were to get rid of the comma before 'that'.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney The reason why I posted this question was, well, mainly to check if there were any other grammar rules that specifically applied to an apposition or a content clause concerning commas. I am glad to hear your confirmation, though, that the rules for (non-)restrictive clauses do still apply, at least for the sake of consistency. The articles provided in the links were also a great read too.

Comment: I’ll see the question as closed. No more answer needed.